# Dynamic Hyperlink in SSRS 2008 for CRM 2011

Tags: reporting-services, hyperlink, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have created one report using SSRS 2008 for CRM 2011 records. Here my requirement is to create an hyperlink for Name column in that table and it has to open that record in CRM.

Eg: For the Account records table, we have a 'Name' column. On click of Name field, it has to open that particular Account record just like subgrid records in CRM.

How can we achieve this in SSRS reports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add CRM_URL parameter to your report parameters list, make it hidden. Then add action to the name column field from the text box properties: go to Text Box Properties->Actions->Go to URL ->add an expression.

Here is the example of the expression you should use:
=Parameters!CRM_URL.Value & "?ID={"&Fields!**accountid**.Value.ToString()&"}&LogicalName=**account**"

Note in the expression above that you have to select the record GUID (in this example, the accountid) in your query.

In my experience, the hyperlink will not work in the SSRS preview while you're designing the report. You'll need to load it to CRM first.